# python sort groupby data by key/function

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I would like to sort the data by the month however not alphabetically rather by the month order, i.e first the sales for January and then February etc,
see the illustrated data I created

```
month=['January','February','March','April','January','February','March','April']
sales=[10,100,130,145,13409,670,560,40]
dict = {'month': month, 'sales': sales}  
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df.groupby('month')['sales'].mean().sort_values()
```

in this case I received data by the sales average, however I would like to sort the value by
the month order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively and probably slower, but just for posterity you can use lambda with map:

```
month_order = {"January": 1, "February": 2, "March": 3, "April": 4}

df = df.sort_values(by="month", key=lambda x: x.map(month_order), ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Before sorting change it to categorical:

```
months = ['January', 'February','March','April']
df['month'] = pd.Categorical(df['month'],categories=months,ordered=True)
df.sort_values(by=['month'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

The output is:

```
      month  sales
0   January     10
4   January  13409
1  February    100
5  February    670
2     March    130
6     March    560
3     April    145
7     April     40
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to sort monthly details in ascending order while sales details are represented in descending order.

```
months = ['January', 'February','March','April']
df['month'] = pd.Categorical(df['month'],categories=months,ordered=True)
df.sort_values(['month', 'sales'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Please go to this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for further reference.